# Drag and Drop with ImageView (NEW)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, overlapping

I am currently on a project using Drag and Drop in Android. What I want to accomplish is, (as seen on the link below) I'll drag the mushroom to the pizza dough then, when I drop it, my ready made picture of mushrooms will be seen together with the pizza dough.

I've made the code already but I am not sure about it. For the mushroom, I used a button and for the pizza dough, I used an `ImageView`. The code below works. What I want to accomplish now, it how to stack images through drag and drop. Just like how the picture/link below demonstrates it.

[image: click to see picture]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1, b2, b3;
    // TextView txt; //
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        b1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
        b2.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
        b3.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

        image.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    }

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };

    View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();

            final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            switch (dragEvent) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                    if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pepperoni);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mushrooms);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pineapples);
                    }
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                    }
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pepperoni);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mushrooms);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pineapples);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```